# Unknown Column in field list MySql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

i just create an `stored procedure` `Scorer` where `parameter` are like this

[image]

this the definition of `Stored procedure`

```
  BEGIN
     set @inser = CONCAT('INSERT INTO activity8',' (ActivityType,ActivityChapter,ActivitySubject,ActivityClass,Student) VALUES (',Type,',',Chapter,',',Subject,',',Class,',',Student,')');

prepare stmt from @inser;
execute stmt ;
End
```

this is the table structure of activity8 table

[image]

now when i call `CALL Scorer('d',2,5,7,38)`

why do it gives error `#1054 - Unknown column 'd' in 'field list'`

**Edit**

it works well when i do `CALL Scorer('"d"',2,5,7,38)` or `CALL Scorer("'d'",2,5,7,38)` can any body explain why ?

Answer (score 2):

If your data is of `varchar` type and you are using `CONCAT` to build your query then it is not gonna work with single quotes as you are seeing already   when you do

```
 set @inser = CONCAT('INSERT INTO activity8',' (ActivityType,ActivityChapter,ActivitySubject,ActivityClass,Student) VALUES (',Type,',',Chapter,',',Subject,',',Class,',',Student,')');
```

when you do `CALL Scorer('d',2,5,7,38);`

it means your query is

```
 @inser = INSERT INTO activity8 (ActivityType,ActivityChapter,ActivitySubject,ActivityClass,Student) VALUES 
(d,2,5,7,38)
```

this is what your query is here your `varchar` type value `d` is without quotes

so one quote is consumed by the  `CONCAT` itself

when you will prepare statement

```
prepare stmt from @inser;
execute stmt ;
```

your `varchar` value `'d'` would be of without quotes

so you have to put your `varchar paramter` in like this `"'d'" or '"d"'`

one quote for `concat` and another  one for the query itself

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotes on d.

```
CALL Scorer("d",2,5,7,38)
```

I think that should help you.

Comment: it works well when i do CALL Scorer('"d"',2,5,7,38)

Comment: can you please explain why ?

Comment: Sure, it's as the error states, using single quotes is treated as a column.

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx

@Ari7, based here, using single quotes is really how it should be when having string as input parameter. So why will it be different on this case?

Comment: but its the first parameter of stored procedure which is declared as varchar as well

Comment: and i am passing this in single quotes as its a varchar type so it should not be the problem

Comment: if its required '" "' quotes being a varchar  then it must be required at least ' ' in my int type of parameter but they are fine without even single quotes

Comment: @jbdeguzman I based my answer on the error. With the change from Chen I think the parser was having trouble recognising it and somehow adding double quotes to it solved it. I'm curious to if two single quotes would work?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Probably because of that "Char" under Options for the "Type" parameter. What does that mean?

Comment: No it not char its charset  if you have used Phpmyadmin  then it the default encoding charset for  varchar type when you add varchar type it appears as default